# Unable to get the AuthenticationResult after redirecting to java web-app

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to integrate azure ad into a java web application using openidconnect approach. My web application is deployed on weblogic application server.

Reference: [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/integrating-azure-ad-into-a-java-web-application/)

Base code that I used is from microsoft github repo: [Link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect.git)

After integration, I was able to redirect my login page to Microsoft login page, entered credential and then when Microsoft redirects back to my login page, it lands in below controller which is my redirect reply URL, here the result object (AuthenticationResult) is null. The session object doesn't seem to have attribute called 'principle'. I am not sure where I have gone wrong, can anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jsp/MyClientControllerServlet")
public class AadController {
    
    
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AadController.class);
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String getDirectoryObjects(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        logger.info("Starting getDirectoryObjects");
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        logger.info("session: "+session);
        //The principle session name variable has the string 'principle'. 
        //I am not sure if this is a static attribute that applies to all applications.
        //I guess this attribute is not available on my HttpSession which is why my AuthenticationResult is null
        AuthenticationResult result = (AuthenticationResult) session.getAttribute(AuthHelper.PRINCIPAL_SESSION_NAME);
        if (result == null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", new Exception("AuthenticationResult not found in session."));
            return "/error";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login session success");
```

Update #1:  I tried to print contents of my HttpSession by enumerating on it and I find that it has just one attribute called 'states' which is empty as well.

From my logs:

```
INFO  BasicFilter:81 - doFilter
INFO  BasicFilter:134 - processAuthenticationData
INFO  AuthenticationAuthority:149 - [Correlation ID: 546546454-18e3-499e-8cc9-0ABCDf3a3584] Instance discovery was successful
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:693 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing POST request for [/myPortal/jsp/MyClientControllerServlet]
DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:221 - Mapping [/jsp/MyClientControllerServlet] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [com.microsoft.aad.adal4jsample.AadController@50f6da2b] and 2 interceptors
DEBUG HandlerMethodInvoker:173 - Invoking request handler method: public java.lang.String com.microsoft.aad.adal4jsample.AadController.getDirectoryObjects(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO  AadController:54 - Starting getDirectoryObjects
INFO  AadController:56 - session: weblogic.servlet.internal.session.MemorySessionData@17d119dd
INFO  AadController:61 - states : {}
```

Update #2:
I tried to print attributes of HttpServletRequest object by enumerating on it and one of the attribute is called error which has this value.

```
INFO  AadController:81 - error : com/nimbusds/jose/shaded/json/parser/ParseException
```

Comment: Which sample are you using? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/tree/master or https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample? And please provide more error messages. What can be seen when the app Microsoft redirects back to your page?

Comment: Hi Allen, I am using the sample from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/tree/master . 
When the microsoft redirects back to my page, on the UI side I see below message:
[  
ERROR PAGE!
com/nimbusds/jose/shaded/json/parser/ParseException

Home Page]

The logs doesn't show a stacktrace or error but just says that result is null (AuthenticationResult result = (AuthenticationResult) session.getAttribute(AuthHelper.PRINCIPAL_SESSION_NAME); ) and attempts to display error.jsp file which shows the above message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding more logs as suggested by @Allen Wu, I was able to finally obtain a glaring stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/nimbusds/jose/shaded/json/parser/ParseException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

The nimbusds [site](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) says their latest release supports JDK 7+ versions, but the latest jar version 9.9.3 supports from JDK 8+ only, hence the above error. After I replaced with version 7.8 (randomly picked a lower version) the application worked right away.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>7.8</version>
</dependency>
```